# Cannot inject RESOURCE_LOCAL container managed EntityManagers using @PersistenceContext

Tags: java, rest, jboss6.x

I am trying to deploy a restfull webservice on jboss6 and facing the following problem..

```
12:13:54,437 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-4) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."copl.war".INSTALL: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."copl.war".INSTALL: JBAS018733: Failed to process phase INSTALL of deployment "copl.war"
        at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:127) [jboss-as-server-7.3.0.Final-redhat-14.jar:7.3.0.Final-redhat-14]
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811) [jboss-msc-1.0.4.GA-redhat-1.jar:1.0.4.GA-redhat-1]
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746) [jboss-msc-1.0.4.GA-redhat-1.jar:1.0.4.GA-redhat-1]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110) [rt.jar:1.7.0_04]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603) [rt.jar:1.7.0_04]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722) [rt.jar:1.7.0_04]
Caused by: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: JBAS011047: Component class au.com.copl.bean.ServiceBean for component ServiceBean has errors:
JBAS011428: Cannot inject RESOURCE_LOCAL container managed EntityManagers using @PersistenceContext
        at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.ModuleJndiBindingProcessor$1.handle(ModuleJndiBindingProcessor.java:171)
        at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ClassDescriptionTraversal.run(ClassDescriptionTraversal.java:54)
        at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.ModuleJndiBindingProcessor.processClassConfigurations(ModuleJndiBindingProcessor.java:164)
        at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.ModuleJndiBindingProcessor.deploy(ModuleJndiBindingProcessor.java:157)
        at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:120) [jboss-as-server-7.3.0.Final-redhat-14.jar:7.3.0.Final-redhat-14]
    ... 5 more
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use transaction-type=JTA in persistence.xml. Hopefully issue would be resolved.

Comment: I have replaced Transaction-Type=RESOURCE_LOCAL  to Transaction-Type=JTA .. Now working fine.
Why cannot use RESOURCE_LOCAL ??
please help me anyone in detail. 
What is the actual problem.

Comment: I have already deployed in jboss4.2 with RESOURCE_LOCAL, But there are no exception on that environment. this exception come on when I deploy the jboss6.